# Buying used copy of GTA V

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I'm about to buy a used copy of GTA V off of Craigslist. As long as I have the discs, I can still play it, right? Just checking that this isn't a scam somehow. I haven't played any 360 games in a long time.

Comment: I'd follow standard Craigslist precautions, but assuming it is the real disc, there should be no technical reason for it to not work, I don't think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the discs are intact, there should be no issue with it being a second hand copy. GTA 5 does not use "online passes" that have been popular in this console generation.